# Is this matrix a root of the given polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is whether a given matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & c & d\\
0 & 2 & e & f \\
0 & 0 & 3 & g \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
satisfies $f(A) = A^2 - 5A +4I=0$?

My attempt was to use the Cayley–Hamilton theorem 
$$
\Delta(\lambda)=\Pi_{k=1}^4(\lambda - k)^4 = (\lambda-2)(\lambda-3)(\lambda^2-5\lambda+4)=0.
$$
Then
$$
\Delta(A) = (A-2)(A-3)(A^2-5A+4)=(A-2)(A-3)f(A)=0.
$$
But in general it does not mean that $f(A)$ is $0$. Moreover, by some numeric examples I see that in general $f(A)\neq0$. Is there any theorem or consequnce that I am missing?

Comment: If it would have been real numbers it would have been possible that too if $(a-3)$ and $(a-2)$ were not zero then $f(a)$ would have been $0$ , but in case of Matix multiplication this is not the case that is $A.B = 0$ is alsopossible even when $A \neq 0$ and $B \neq 0$ ,here in latter $0$ is the zero matrix

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is no, because if $f(A)=0$, then $f$ would be a multiple of the minimal polynomial of $A$. However this matrix has $4$ simple eigenvalues: $1, 2, 3, 4$; hence its minimal polynomial has degree $4$, and it can't divide a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Thanks! That is the exact answer that I was looking for. The other 2 are right and elegant as well but this question was in a context of eigenvalues and etc., therefore your answer is what they meant in the book.Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

We can simply compute the element $b_{2,2}$ of the resulting matrix $(b_{i,j})=A^2-5A+4I$. We have $$b_{2,2}=2^2-5\cdot 2 + 4=-2 \not = 0.$$

Comment: Note that this is because the second standard basis vector is an obvious eigenvector for eigenvalue$~2$, which as calculated here is a non-root of $X^2-5X+4$.

Comment: @Marc: no need to involve eigenvectors. For a triangular matrix, $f (A)_{2,2}=f (A_{2,2}) $.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: You are right, the answer reasons directly about matrix coefficients, not (as I was tempted to do) about eigenvectors. Of course every diagonal coefficient of a triangular matrix is an eigenvalue, but one does not need to invoke that here.

Answer (score 2):

We can proceed by method of contradiction.
Suppose $f(A) = A^2 - 5A + 4I$, applying Trace to both sides we see that

$\operatorname{Trace}(A^2) = 30$, $\operatorname{Trace}(A) = 10$

thus $\operatorname{Trace}(A^2 - 5A + 4I) = \operatorname{Trace} (A^2) - 5\cdot\operatorname{Trace} (A) + 4\cdot\operatorname{Trace} (I)$

We see $\operatorname{Trace}(A^2 - 5A + 4I) = -16$, but $\operatorname{Trace}(f(A)) = 0$, from the definition of $f(A)$, and thus a contradiction

Hope this helps.

Comment: Combining the usual text and math in this way seems a bit unusual to me. (But it might be a matter of taste.) But still it might be useful for you to know that you can type things like `$\operatorname{Trace}(A)$` $\operatorname{Trace}(A)$ or `$\operatorname{Tr}(A)$` $\operatorname{Tr}(A)$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thankyou for pointing out.

Comment: I have edited your post a bit. Feel free to rollback my edit (or improve it further) if this is not what you want it to look like.